# Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication change username field

Tags: perl, authentication, catalyst

I'm using [Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication) for user authentication in my [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) app, and I'd like to be able to change the username field that it uses when authenticating users (currently it defaults to username). Here is my current set up:

```
#used for user authentication 
__PACKAGE__->config(
    authentication => {
    default_realm => 'users',
    realms        => {
        users => {
            credential => {
               class          => 'Password',
               password_field => 'password',
               password_type  => 'self_check'
            },  
        store => {
           class         => 'DBIx::Class',
           user_model    => 'DB::User',
           role_relation => 'roles',
           role_field    => 'name',
        }   
      }
    }
  }    
);
```

As you can see, there is an option to set the name of the password field, simply by setting `password_field`. I tried using the same thing with `username_field`, however it didn't work. I've looked in the documentation, but I can't seem to find anything on it. Does anyone know of a way I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The quote from man of [Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class):

> **id_field**
>
> In most cases, this config variable does not need to be set, as Catalyst::Authentication::Store::DBIx::Class will determine the primary key of the user table on its own. If you need to override the default, or your user table has multiple primary keys, then id_field should contain the column name that should be used to restore the user. A given value in this column should correspond to a single user in the database.

So you have to do this:

```
store => {
           class         => 'DBIx::Class',
           user_model    => 'DB::User',
           role_relation => 'roles',
           role_field    => 'name',
           id_field      => 'name_of_user'  # A new name of column in your DB
        }
```

than I have to call authenticate method with new column name of user:

```
$c->authenticate( { name_of_user => $user, password => $password } );
```

That's all!

Comment: But I'm not looking to change what it recognizes as the primary key, I want to change how `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication` defaults to looking for a column named `username` to authenticate.

Comment: That's right! You may use any column in your table to recognize an user NOT ONLY as primary key. Just try to do it.